# What is the purpose of having multiple Kafka partitions on the same host?

Tags: apache-kafka

Consider the following setup:

- A single Kafka host
- A single Topic
- Multiple partitions

In such case, all partitions are on the same physical host.

My understanding is that partitions perform three functions:

- Data resiliance
- Load balancing
- Regional distribution? (CDN)

I am not totally sure about the last two of these. I am probably wrong about the final point, because I don't see any mechanism in the Kafka API or setup configuration which would permit this.

To explain each in detail.

##### Data Resiliance:

If there is more than one partition, and messages are replicated to more than one parition, then data is resiliant to the failure of a parition. This can be configured using the "replication factor". The partitions must be on different physical hosts, otherwise this doesn't work.

##### Load Balancing:

Kafka appears to have an automated load balancing mechanism in that messages are distributed to partitions according to a Round-Robin mechanism. If a key is provided with a message, then a hashing algorithm is used to ensure all messages with the same key are distributed to the same partitions, however we still have load balancing in this case because there will be presumably more than one message key in use. (Not all messages have the same key.)

##### CDN:

If Kafka hosts are distributed across the globe, then it would make sense for messages from consumers to be more likely to be distributed to geographically nearby hosts, which would naturally happen because those hosts probably have lower latency and higher bandwidth connections. I believe, although I am not totally sure, that Kafka somewhat behaves like a CDN in this respect, because it does things like automated leader election.

I might be wrong about this however, so please correct me if that is not the case.

##### Single Host or More Partitions than Hosts?

These points raise an interesting question. Since it is possible to have more than one partition on the same host, and we can have more partitions than hosts, what would be the purpose of this?

In the extreme case, with just a single host and a minimum of two partitions, we obtain none of the above described benefits. There is no failover or data resiliance. There is no load balancing effect, or low-latency connection selection effect.

So what purpose would this have?

Reference: https://www.dataversity.net/how-to-overcome-data-order-issues-in-apache-kafka/#

Comment: Just a comment as the answer by OneCreicketeer is as always on point. I would suggest you to read the free book from Confluent [Kafka the Definitive Guide](https://www.confluent.io/resources/kafka-the-definitive-guide-v2/), as it explains some bits in a lot more detail (e.g. partitions, brokers, replicas, mirror maker, etc)

Comment: @Augusto Thanks I'll take a look into this tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Partitions are not for resiliency, and not related to server count. Replicas are, for both.

"Load balancing" isn't preformed in Kafka, as would an HTTP service, for example. Records are hashed and distributed to partitions, as you said, or you can explicitly tell the producer or consumer to write to any available partition. Plus, client requests are *always* to the leader broker of a partition, regardless of load.

Therefore, I say this is not for load balancing (as it has no correlation to server/client load), but rather throughput. If you only have one host, obviously you're limited by disk and network speed of that one machine. Similarly, one machine is a single point of failure, so yes, you should never have more than one broker on a host (Kafka won't even let you set `replication.factor` higher than the broker count). (I guess, in theory, you could run separate Kafka JVM processes, with different disks for log storage, but YMMV, as networking would be weird)

For multiple brokers, clients do not decide partition placement on brokers without manual intervention (`kafka-reassign-partitions`). This is where load *distribution* comes into account, but it's *distributed* on "best effort, bin packing", still not "load" because the broker cannot anticipate how the partitions will be used. So, when multiple partitions are used on a host, and you have multi-core CPU and multiple physical disks mounted to volumes set by Kafka `log.dirs`, only then would load be properly balanced within one machine. **But**, this still is up to the client to read/write uniformly distributed data, otherwise you get "hot partitions" and start filling disks, and taking brokers offline. If the data is always keyless, and always using default partitioner, should have nothing to worry about.

Kafka (and Zookeeper) prefer low latency, so no, one cluster should not be "global". It's recommended you don't deploy a cluster beyond availability zones in cloud providers (regionally isolated, separate data centers). If you needed a globally distributed Kafka setup, you'd deploy regional clusters, and use tooling such as MirrorMaker2, Confluent Cluster Links, etc, or switch to other projects like Apache Pulsar (and enable its Kafka client compatible features)

Regarding the referenced blog, Kafka does not automatically rebalance itself when brokers are added, or when partitions of topics are increased.